# default constructor cannot handle exception type ioexception thrown by implicit super constructor

Tags: java, java-io

I already looked for similar treads but i cannot find an answer since those posts are like 3 or 4 years old and cant ask people there due to my low reputation ill make another thread.

`

```
File file1 = new File("file1.txt");

File file2 = new File("file2.txt");

boolean isTwoEqual = FileUtils.contentEquals(file1,file2);

{ 

if (isTwoEqual == true)

System.out.println("You have no new grades");

else 
     System.out.println("You have new grade.");

}`
```

So i need to check if two .txt files are equal.
Im getting an error saying  "default constructor cannot handle exception type ioexception thrown by implicit super constructor"
Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: What third library you're using? `FileUtils` is **not** the part of standard JDK

Comment: im sorry my bad. im using this one.   https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/

Comment: It's O.K., just add the tag to your question.

Comment: What line generates the error?.

Comment: Can you include the code which gets the error? There are no constructors in your example.

Comment: Is the included code inside a constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error means that you have this going on:

```
public class SomeParentClass {
    public SomeParentClass() throws IOException {
        // This is a parent class; maybe you wrote it, maybe you're using one.
        // note: It declares that it throws IOException!
    }
}
```

and you're writing:

```
public class MyClass extends SomeParentClass {}
```

the problem is as follows: Any class you write MUST have at least one constructor. Note here that 'MyClass' has zero defined constructors; when you do that, and you try to compile that file, javac will make one for you. Javac is very predictable; it always makes this constructor:

```
public MyClass() {
    super();
}
```

And so it does, here. Unfortunately, that's a problem: the `super()` call can throw IOException and you need to handle that. The easiest solution to this problem is to write your own actual constructor; don't rely on javac to make it for you. So, add this:

```
public MyClass() throws IOException {
    super();
}
```

and the compiler error will go away.